# How to increment assembly info and check-in (commit) to source control

Tags: .net, tfs, build-process, tfs-2015

In the new build system offered by TFS 2015, how would you accomplish the task of increasing the assembly version but *checking it into the source control as well*?

I would like to have the current version always available in the source control written in AssemblyInfo files.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell script below (quoted from this [blog](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/matching-binary-version-to-build-number-version-in-tfs-2013-builds)) modify AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion values in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY directory.

Don't tested it myself, you can have a try to add a variable which targets to the server path which hosts the AssemblyInfo.cs and replace TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY with it.

```html
Param(
  [string]$pathToSearch = $env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY,
  [string]$buildNumber = $env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER,
  [string]$searchFilter = "AssemblyInfo.*",
  [regex]$pattern = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
)
 
try
{
    if ($buildNumber -match $pattern -ne $true) {
        Write-Host "Could not extract a version from [$buildNumber] using pattern [$pattern]"
        exit 1
    } else {
        $extractedBuildNumber = $Matches[0]
        Write-Host "Using version $extractedBuildNumber"
 
        gci -Path $pathToSearch -Filter $searchFilter -Recurse | %{
            Write-Host "  -> Changing $($_.FullName)"
         
            # remove the read-only bit on the file
            sp $_.FullName IsReadOnly $false
 
            # run the regex replace
            (gc $_.FullName) | % { $_ -replace $pattern, $extractedBuildNumber } | sc $_.FullName
        }
 
        Write-Host "Done!"
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_
    exit 1
}
```